Designing battery voltage measurement with passive balancing
At work I have been busy designing a circuit for measuring the voltages of three batteries that are connected in series to each other. A microcontroller will read the voltages and determine which is the fullest and it will send a signal to a MOSFET with a resistor connected to it, so that the resistor will dissipate some of the energy of the battery (that is the fullest). But I just can’t figure out how to correctly connect the MOSFET. This is the best that I have come up with.

S2 is the high signal from the microcontroller that I am simulating with a simple switch. The reason V4 is smaller is to simulate how circuit reacts if one of the battery has a smaller voltage. The circuit needs to be eventually be connected to every battery. The problem is that the voltage on the source pin of the MOSFET too high is to switch it with VDD and but I’ve been pulling my hair out for hours trying to think of a solution, but I just can’t find the right way to do this.
So my question is: how can I make this work?
If there any questions or I need to make something clear, let me know!
Thanks,
DJ

Did you consider using a P-FET and turn it on by pulling the gate low?

You can gen "optoFET" (MOSFET with photodiode in gate). Using that you can significantly reduce complextity - just simply connect its "gate" (IR LED) directly to MCU output no matter on which potential is MOSFET itself.

You could use opt-isolators to switch them something like this:

This would allow each one to be isolated from the micro circuit (R5 is just so LTspice doesn't complain).
Each one would use the voltage from its own battery so you wouldn't have to worry about them being lifted above ground.

If you use a P-FET to switch the bleeder current, you don't need an additional supply voltage at the high side.
Just pulling the gate down to GND would exceed the maximum gate voltage, so I added a constant current driver circuit formed by Q1 and R1.
If the MCU supply is off or GPIO_OUT is high, there will be no base current and the voltage across R2 is 0V and M1 is not conducting.
If GPIO_OUT is low, the base current is enabled and limited to around 0.5 mA by R1.
I = (MCU_VCC - Vbe) / R1,
2.7 V / 5.6 kΩ = 0.48 mA
The resulting gate voltage is around 10 V and defined by R2.
U = I.R2 * R2,
0.48 mA * 22kΩ = 10.56 V
The same circuit can be used for all 3 bleeding circuits.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
